# I try to do a TicTacToe project myself, but the py close after i enter the very first input

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

[the window of game.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSASG.png) I try out some of the python beginner project to practise my sense of coding.
And after i followed the youtube video step by step, i started to debug and play the
TicTacToe. **It closed right after i input my first square/input. But i don't understand
where it goes wrong.** I just start fighting with coding, i don't mind to get slap right out
of my face right now. Please, go easy on me. It keeps drive me to the wall.

```
#Player.py ||||
import math
import random

class Player:
    def __init__(self,letter):

        self.letter = letter

    def  get_move(self,game):
        pass


class RandomComputerPlayer(Player):

    def __init__(self, letter):
        super().__init__(letter)

    def  get_move(self,game):
        square = random.choice(game.available_moves())
        return square


class HumanPlayer(Player):

    def __init__(self, letter):
        super().__init__(letter)

    def  get_move(self,game):
        valid_square = False
        val = None
        while not valid_square:
            square = input(self.letter + '\'s turn. Input move (0-8):')

            try:
                val = int(square)
                if val not in game.available_moves():
                    raise ValueError
                valid_square = True
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid square. Try again.')
        return val
```

---

And here's `game.py`:

```
#game.py ||||
import time
from player import HumanPlayer, RandomComputerPlayer

class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [' ' for _ in range(9)]
        self.current_winner = None

    def print_board(self):
        for row in [self.board[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(3)]:
            print('| ' + ' | ' .join(row) + ' |')

    @staticmethod
    def print_board_nums():
        # 0 | 1 | 2 etc
        number_board = [[str(i) for i in range(j*3, (j+1)*3)] for j in range (3)]
        for row in number_board:
            print('| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')

    def available_moves(self):

        moves = []
        for (i, x) in enumerate(self.board):
            if spot == ' ':
                moves.append(i)

    def empty_squares(self):
        return ' ' in self.board

    def num_empty_squares(self):
        return len(self.available_moves())

    def make_move(self, square, letter):
        if self.board[square] == ' ':
            self.board[square] = letter
            if self.winner(square, letter):
                self.current_winner = letter
            return True
        return False

    def winner(self, square, letter):
        # winner if 3 in a row anywhere, check all of the possiblity
        row_ind = square // 3
        row = self.board[row_ind*3 : (row_ind + 1) * 3]
        if all ([spot == letter for spot in row]):
            return True
        
        col_ind = square % 3
        column = [self.board[col_ind + i*3] for i in range(3)]
        if all ([spot == letter for spot in column]):
            return True

        # check diagonals
        if square % 2 == 0:
            diagonal1 = [self.board[i] for i in[0,4,8]]
            if all ([spot == letter for spot in diagonal1]):
                return True
            diagonal2 = [self.board[i] for i in[2,4,6]]
            if all ([spot == letter for spot in diagonal2]):
                return True

        # if all of the possibility not happen
        return False



def play(game, x_player, o_player, print_game = True):
    # returns the winner of the game! or None for a tie
    if print_game:
        game.print_board_nums()
    letter = 'X'

    while game.empty_squares():
        if letter == '0':
            square = o_player.get_move(game)
        else:
            square = x_player.get_move(game)

        if game.make_move(square, letter):
            if print_game:
                print(letter + ' makes a move to square {square}')
                game.print_board()
                print('') # empty line

            if game.current_winner:
                if print_game:
                    print(letter + 'wins!')
                return letter

            letter = 'O' if letter == 'X' else 'X'
            # if letter == 'X':
            #   letter = 'O'
            # else:
            #   letter = 'X'

        time.sleep(0.8)


    if print_game:
        print('It\'s a tie!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_player = HumanPlayer('X')
    o_player = RandomComputerPlayer('O')
    t = TicTacToe()
    play(t, x_player, o_player, print_game = True)
```

Comment: Your code is crashing - please include the tracebacks you're getting.

Comment: **What** closes? You don't open any windows. Also please read [mre]

Comment: Please provide the error as well.

Comment: It's actually really fun and easy to solve stuff like this - you can actually step through your code, as it's executing line-by-line, and see exactly what is going on; and thus see where the execution starts deviating from your expectations. It's called debugging; there are tools called debuggers that come with most IDEs, which have a graphical interface that makes it really easy to see what's going on. PyCharm is free and it has a wonderful debugger, here's an article on it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: You have two rather minor mistakes, both In `available_moves`.  Your for loop puts the cell value in `x` but you are comparing `spot`.  You need to make those two names the same.  Second, you need to `return moves` when the loop is done.

Comment: I use visual studio to edit the code, it appears no errors. When i open the game.py, it pops a cmd panel and let me input the integer as i coded. But right after i enter it, the cmd window closed...
I just start my stackoverflow account today and i have so much to learn more about this and python. And thank you for giving me suggestions to me, it really helps a lot. :')

Comment: Also, probably all of us saw the stack trace by just running your code, but here's an example of what we all saw: [traceback image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veFNK.png) - that makes it much clearer why your code crashed.

Answer (score 1):

When I copied the code and ran it locally on my computer, the traceback showed that there was an error in `game.py`, specifically in your `available_moves()` function.

```
def available_moves(self):

    moves = []
    for (i, x) in enumerate(self.board):
        if spot == ' ':
            moves.append(i)
```

The traceback specifically says, `NameError: name 'spot' is not defined`, which is true since `spot` is not defined. I am assuming `spot` and `x` are supposed to mean the same here since you are looking at the square on your Tic-Tac-Toe board. Also, this function should probably return `moves`; otherwise, any other function calling `available_moves()` is going to get a value of type `None` instead of the list of available moves.

```
def available_moves(self):
    moves = []

    # iterate through all spots on board
    for (i, spot) in enumerate(self.board):
        # if a spot is empty, add its index to moves
        if spot == ' ':
            moves.append(i)

    return moves
```

Also I've been absolutely crushing myself against myself playing this game so thanks for that!

Edit: Just noticed after posting this that Tim Roberts basically summed up my answer. Oops.

Comment: How can you find out the error so fast? Is there any hint or sense that i am lack of?
Debugging make me struggle a lot.

Comment: @0598778 it prints in the window after you run the program and it crashes - I similarly ran your code and fixed the two bugs quickly. However, you mentioned that you're running this via Visual Studio and the console window closed immediately after your program crashed, which made it so that you couldn't see the messages. I think VS has a way to disable that behavior, otherwise I'd recommend either using VS Code or learning to run your Python from the command line first, to understand it all better - https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#getting-started (if you're using windows)

Comment: I used my computer's terminal/command line to look at the error traceback. If you go on your command line, navigate to where your Tic Tac Toe project is, and run it `python3 game.py`, the code will run there. You can see errors printed there as well, which is how I found yours. Hope this helps! :)))